# C# selected calendar days into datagridview columns

Tags: c#, calendar, datasource

I'm creating this function for my attendance monitoring system, now I want to have a datagridview (or if you can suggest some other way) that will show the school days based on the calendar (with out sat. and sun.)

Similar to this, the highlighted part:

[image: similar to this, the highlighted part.]

As columns and it will change depending on the filter that I select in my combobox.

e.g. I selected January and only the school days of January will be the header.
I just have these 2 questions:
1. How can I make the selected days (of month selected in combobox) to headers of column.
2. what will be my datasource? should I create a database for it?

Help me out, I can't quite get the logic needed here.

Comment: The "Data" in Database and `DataSource` are different things.

Comment: OK, thanks for the info, I'll keep that in mind! :D